# Can I use the embedded ST-LINK/V2-1 USB of an STM32 Nucleo board to create a USB mass storage application?

Tags: usb, stm32, st-link

I want to create an application that can act as a USB mass storage device in order to provide its output to other devices. Mostly results from A/D conversion of signals.

I have an [STM32L412 Nucleo-32 board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l412kb.html) lying around that I'd like to use (both for development and running the application)
It has a USB Micro-B plug for programming.
[ST-LINK/V2-1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj5urPlysjqAhWwtYsKHUHsAf4QFjABegQICBAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Ftechnical_note%2Fdm00290229-overview-of-stlink-derivatives-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3H52mKCpFsXXs4crfxr6n-) supports

> Mass storage interface on USB

As far as I understand, that allows flashing the chip via USB mass storage, which is quite nice.

**I wonder if I could also use the USB plug from my application on the chip to make it act like a USB mass storage device when my application is running?** That would save me from wiring up another USB plug to the board.

Comment: In addition to this not being supported, USB Mass Storage is *definitely not* what you want to use for A/D converter output.  If you *have* to borrow something, USB-CDC would be much closer to being a fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, most likely you don't want to change that. The USB connector is for the onboard ST-LINK MCU. It runs its own firmware to make it the ST-LINK it is.

It will connect to the target STM32 with SWD/JTAG for programming and debugging purposes. It has just the mass storage interface for programming the target.

So it can't be used for anything else, unless you erase and reprogram the ST-LINK MCU, but then you would lose it being the onboard ST-LINK so programming and debugging would not be possible.